# Ignoring capital letters when checking if a string contains a word

Tags: java

I can't seem to figure out how to make it so when I am checking to see if a string contains a certain word, it ignores the capital letters within the word.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the comparing string to lowercase.

```
String s = "ABC";
if (s.toLowerCase().contains("abc")); //returns true
```

But if it were me..

```
s.equalsIgnoreCase("abc");
```

can be used if you're comparing the entire String. Which is fine.

But in general, Google these types of questions first. There are millions of answers for this exact question.